# angular UI bootstrap throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to angular-Js. I am trying to use the bootstrap angular UI as part of my learning I have taken code from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

the accordian module. http://imgur.com/h1IFF0g

But on page load I am getting below error for each accordion component.

> VM5120:27 TypeError: $q.resolve is not a function  at collapse (ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js:66)
>   at Object.fn (ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js:102)
>   at l.$digest (angular.js:14243)
>   at l.$apply (angular.js:14506)
>   at l (angular.js:9659)
>   at S (angular.js:9849)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.D.onload (angular.js:9790)

I am declaring dependency in my app.js file as

```
   var mainApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'myApp.view1','myApp.view2', 'myApp.login', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

I have downloaded the ui-bootstrap-1.3.3.js and included them in my project as below.

```
<script src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="ui-bootstrap-1.3.3.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Could someone please guide me in understand where I am doing wrong.

Please let me know if I need to provide any further information.

Comment: don't need both scripts.Second includes all that is in first...plus templates. What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Thank you for correcting, I am very new to front end. I have updated the post with references I am using. It is 1.3.14 I am using.

Answer (score 2):

I could resolve it by changing the angular js version to 1.4.3.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5490 helped me.

Thank you!!